# Can I use scatter function in matplotlib without specifying x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark

I am trying to use the scatter view in matplotlib on a single column dataframe like so:

```
uva1pd.plot(kind='scatter', y='RESULT')
```

This is the dataframe:

```
      RESULT
0    2009.13
1    1999.19
2    2014.34
3    1987.51
4    1987.51
..       ...
475  1999.35
476  1987.51
477  1993.19
478  1993.19
479  1982.62
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
An error was encountered:
scatter requires an x and y column
```

Is there a way to just use the default rownumber of index of the dataframe in matplotlib?

Comment: Could you show an example of your dataframe...

Comment: You can use `scatter(range(len(y)), y)`

Comment: @user32882, I have updated my question with the dataframe result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in which you wouldn't have to define a new variable...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'data':[5,89,7,1,56,8]})

plt.scatter(d.index, d['data'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a dummy x variable with the length equal to the y column -

```
y = np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10,))
x = np.arange(0,len(y)) #dummy x
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Akshay Sehgal Thank you for this solution. I did not mention in my question, but I am converting the data frame from RDD to panda and it is compute-intensive. So I am trying to avoid adding more columns/data.

Comment: My approach doesn't add any new columns. I am creating 2 independent numpy arrays. Infact my approach doesnt need you to convert your data into pandas atall, you can simply keep the array of data in y and use x as in code to generate the graph, WITHOUT conversion to pandas. Therefore it will be way faster than a pandas approach.

Comment: That's interesting. Would I be able to use it while the data is in RDD form, instead of using `collect()` ?

Comment: Yes, just do `a = np.array(testRdd.collect())` . The `.collect()` already returns an array which can be set to a numpy array, without the heavy dataframe transformation.